# Interfacing SIM800L with PPP [LCP Terminated by Peer]

Tags: raspbian, serial, uart, gsm

I am using SIM800L, and managed to interface it with RPi3.

After successful configuration on `/etc/ppp/peers/rnet`, my file looks like this

```
connect "/usr/sbin/chat -v -f /etc/chatscripts/gprs -T airtelgprs.com"
/dev/serial0
9600
noipdefault
usepeerdns
replacedefaultroute
defaultroute
persist
noauth
nocrtscts
local
```

And the ppp configuration on `/etc/network/interfaces.d/rnet` looks like this

```
auto rnet
iface rnet inet ppp
provider rnet
```

So when I run `sudo pon rnet`, the log appends in `/var/log/syslog` as follows:

```
Jun 23 13:44:21 raspberrypi chat[2150]: abort on (BUSY)
Jun 23 13:44:21 raspberrypi chat[2150]: abort on (VOICE)
Jun 23 13:44:21 raspberrypi chat[2150]: abort on (NO CARRIER)
Jun 23 13:44:21 raspberrypi chat[2150]: abort on (NO DIALTONE)
Jun 23 13:44:21 raspberrypi chat[2150]: abort on (NO DIAL TONE)
Jun 23 13:44:21 raspberrypi chat[2150]: abort on (NO ANSWER)
Jun 23 13:44:21 raspberrypi chat[2150]: abort on (DELAYED)
Jun 23 13:44:21 raspberrypi chat[2150]: abort on (ERROR)
Jun 23 13:44:21 raspberrypi chat[2150]: abort on (+CGATT: 0)
Jun 23 13:44:21 raspberrypi chat[2150]: send (AT^M)
Jun 23 13:44:21 raspberrypi chat[2150]: timeout set to 12 seconds
Jun 23 13:44:21 raspberrypi chat[2150]: expect (OK)
Jun 23 13:44:21 raspberrypi chat[2150]: AT^M^M
Jun 23 13:44:21 raspberrypi chat[2150]: OK
Jun 23 13:44:21 raspberrypi chat[2150]:  -- got it
Jun 23 13:44:21 raspberrypi chat[2150]: send (ATH^M)
Jun 23 13:44:21 raspberrypi chat[2150]: expect (OK)
Jun 23 13:44:21 raspberrypi chat[2150]: ^M
Jun 23 13:44:21 raspberrypi chat[2150]: ^M
Jun 23 13:44:21 raspberrypi chat[2150]: +CPIN: READY^M
Jun 23 13:44:21 raspberrypi chat[2150]: ATH^M^M
Jun 23 13:44:21 raspberrypi chat[2150]: OK
Jun 23 13:44:21 raspberrypi chat[2150]:  -- got it
Jun 23 13:44:21 raspberrypi chat[2150]: send (ATE1^M)
Jun 23 13:44:21 raspberrypi chat[2150]: expect (OK)
Jun 23 13:44:21 raspberrypi chat[2150]: ^M
Jun 23 13:44:21 raspberrypi chat[2150]: ATE1^M^M
Jun 23 13:44:21 raspberrypi chat[2150]: OK
Jun 23 13:44:21 raspberrypi chat[2150]:  -- got it
Jun 23 13:44:21 raspberrypi chat[2150]: send (AT+CGDCONT=1,"IP","airtelgprs.com","",0,0^M)
Jun 23 13:44:21 raspberrypi chat[2150]: expect (OK)
Jun 23 13:44:21 raspberrypi chat[2150]: ^M
Jun 23 13:44:21 raspberrypi chat[2150]: AT+CGDCONT=1,"IP","airtelgprs.com","",0,0^M^M
Jun 23 13:44:21 raspberrypi chat[2150]: OK
Jun 23 13:44:21 raspberrypi chat[2150]:  -- got it
Jun 23 13:44:21 raspberrypi chat[2150]: send (ATD*99#^M)
Jun 23 13:44:21 raspberrypi chat[2150]: timeout set to 22 seconds
Jun 23 13:44:21 raspberrypi chat[2150]: expect (CONNECT)
Jun 23 13:44:21 raspberrypi chat[2150]: ^M
Jun 23 13:44:21 raspberrypi chat[2150]: ATD*99#^M^M
Jun 23 13:44:21 raspberrypi chat[2150]: CONNECT
Jun 23 13:44:21 raspberrypi chat[2150]:  -- got it
Jun 23 13:44:21 raspberrypi chat[2150]: send (^M)
Jun 23 13:44:21 raspberrypi pppd[2114]: Serial connection established.
Jun 23 13:44:21 raspberrypi pppd[2114]: Using interface ppp0
Jun 23 13:44:21 raspberrypi pppd[2114]: Connect: ppp0 <--> /dev/serial0
Jun 23 13:44:23 raspberrypi pppd[2114]: PAP authentication succeeded
Jun 23 13:44:23 raspberrypi pppd[2114]: LCP terminated by peer
Jun 23 13:44:26 raspberrypi pppd[2114]: Connection terminated.
Jun 23 13:44:26 raspberrypi pppd[2114]: Modem hangup
```

So I do not know what I am missing. There is no proper guide on internet as far as I looked. If someone finds something, please let me know. I will also write a blog on this when a proper soution is found for the same.

Comment: As your `chat` succeeds but your `pppd` doesn't, you need more debug information from `pppd`, see the `debug` option.

Comment: @RalfFriedl - Does PAP authentication succeeded means modem worked? And LCP is a host thing right? Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Not only the modem part, but also the authentication part of PPP. LCP is another part of PPP. Turn on PPP debugging, turn off chat debugging and edit the results into the question.